# Polynomial of degree less or equal 2

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, polynomials

Please help me to prove the following result:

Let $V(x)$ be a non constant polynomial of degree less or equal two give by $V(x)=\sum_{i=1}^d\mu_ix_i+\sum_{i=1}^d\frac{\nu_i}{2}x_i^2$. We denote $$Hess\; V=\begin{pmatrix}
\nu_{1} &  0  & \ldots & 0\\
0  &  \nu_{2} & \ldots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0  &   0       &\ldots & \nu_{d}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

its Hessian matrix.

> If $det(Hess\; V)=0$, we can always find an orthonormal basis, in which $V(x)$ takes the form $$V(x)=V_0+\lambda_1x_1+\sum_{i=2}^d\frac{\nu_i}{2}x_i^2$$

where $\lambda_1>0$

Thanks

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your question. The Hessian matrix only takes that particular form if the polynomial already is written in that form.

Comment: it takes this form if $V(x)=\sum_{i=1}^d\mu_ix_i+\sum_{i=1}^d\frac{\nu_i}{2}x_i^2$

Comment: How do **you** define the Hessian of a polynomial in one variable? And even if $\;x\;$ is a vector in several variables, why do you believe its Hessian is diagonal?

Comment: @siwar You really need to edit your question and make it crystal clear. People has a hard time guessing what askers may have wanted...

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: the hypothesis implies $\partial_{x_1}\partial_{x_i}V(0)=0$ for all $i\ge 1$ but why does that imply $\partial_{x_i}V(0)=0$ all $i\ge 2$?

Comment: @ DonAntonio , every symetric matrix is diagonalizable

Answer (score 0):

As originally stated, the result is false. The zero polynomial  is of indicated form (with all $\mu_i=\nu_i = 0$) but there is no orthogonal change of variable that puts it in form $V(x)=\lambda_1 x_1$ with $\lambda_1>0$.  Because the vanishing-of-the-gradient-at-zero property is invariant with respect to orthogonal change of variables.

As edited, the result is trivially true.  The assumptions  force $V(x)=\langle \mu,x\rangle$ with $\mu\ne0$ to be linear.  There is an orthogonal matrix $O$ such that the first row of $O$ is a positive multiple of $\mu$.  That matrix gives the desired change of variables.

Comment: but i am interested about  non constant polynomials

Comment: But you didn't say so.  You asked for a proof of a false statement.  Maybe you should rethink what you want to prove and how to express it more precisely.

Comment: if the polynomial is zero there is no need to ask the question